# filter the date of the event on a specific day for all months xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

in this case I want to filter the date of the event on a specific day for all months,
but I can't. do you have any ideas.

my file.xml

```
    <agenda xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Exercice5.xsd">
        <evenement numero="1">
            <description>hhfhf</description>
            <lieu>4 rue saint leonard</lieu>
            <information>2001-10-26</information>
        </evenement>
        <evenement numero="2">
            <description>hhfhf</description>
            <lieu>4 rue saint leonard</lieu>
            <information>2001-10-26</information>
        </evenement>
</agenda>
```

my file .XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="agenda">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="evenement" type="Evenement"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="uniquekey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="evenement"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@numero"/>
        </xsd:key>
    </xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="Evenement">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="lieu" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="information" type="xsd:date"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="numero" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

thanks you for your help.

Comment: I have an agenda which contains events each event is defined by its information.
this information I will have to assign a date to it. for example this event will take place every first Saturday of every month

Comment: "Filtering" suggests that you are doing something like processing or transforming or querying the XML instance. What technology (or language) are you using to do that? Or are you looking for advice on what technology to use?

Comment: here is the answer